# In Javascript, why is validator requesting 'new' in front of a function invocation?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm using ECMAScript Edition 6, not sure if that's even relevant. Anyway, I'm new to JavaScript and I'm trying to make a script that checks if a file(.pdf) exists and opens it if it does, but if not it opens a default page(.html) that shows where to get the desired file (.pdf). I want to avoid libraries such as jQuery, Bootstrap, AJAX... etc. I'm using "http://www.jslint.com" for validation.
The error is "Expected 'new' before 'UrlExists'.".

Thank you!

```js
// These are declarations of global variables for use with   http://www.jslint.com/
/*global window */
/*global document */
/*global alert */
/*global XMLHttpRequest */

"use strict"; // This is not necessary, but helps catch errors if they occur.

//get id
function  $(id)
{
return document.getElementById(id);
}

// This function is called from the click events triggered by the onload or load function.
// It calls the appropriate function depending on what the UrlExists function returns.
function mylinkclicked(mylocalfile, myurl)
{
    if (UrlExists(mylocalfile))
   {
    alert ("It exists!");
   }
      else
      {
      alert ("It does NOT exists!");
      }
}

// This funtion will run when the page fully loads, and without causing any errors.
function after_all_loads_gogogo()
{
$("undergraduatecatalog").onclick = function() {var mylocalfile = "./local_files/catalog.pdf"; var myurl = "./resource_help/catalogdefault.html"; mylinkclicked(mylocalfile, myurl);};
$("classschedule").onclick = function() {var mylocalfile = "./local_files/schedule/schedule.html"; var myurl = "./resource_help/scheduledefault.html"; mylinkclicked(mylocalfile, myurl);};
$("degreerequirements").onclick = function() {var mylocalfile = "./local_files/degreerequirements.pdf"; var myurl = "./resource_help/degreereqdefault.html"; mylinkclicked(mylocalfile, myurl);};
}

if (window.attachEvent) {window.attachEvent('onload', after_all_loads_gogogo);}
else if (window.addEventListener) {window.addEventListener('load', after_all_loads_gogogo, false);}
else {document.addEventListener('load', after_all_loads_gogogo, false);}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it rather complain that the function does not exist?

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is incomplete code. I didn't want to send the entire 205 lines of code in my question. The good part is that the "final" product runs like glass in Firefox, but sinks like a ship in chrome and ie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is convention to use title case for classes and constructors and use camel or snake case for general functions. The concept, so far as I understand it, is to address an object type properly and distinguish between loose functions and constructors.

Many JS tools have a rule to enforce this, often enabled by default (the ESLint equivalent is [new-cap](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/new-cap)). You can disable them, if you would like, or follow their coding standard and use lowercase letters to start loose functions.

Using TitleCase for classes and camelCase for functions can help identify a class (or static method) reference at a glance. This can be confusing in JS -- even with a naming convention -- since you can make a constructor that doesn't really construct things, invoke constructors without parens, and a number of other interesting language features.